# redcar conflict netbeans

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, redcar

I had a IDE netbeans now I have installed redcar but after
installing redcar my NETBEANS not working so I want to remove redcar
from my local machine(ubuntu 10.10)

when I put this in console:

> sudo gem uninstall redcar

I got

WARNING:  Invalid .gemspec format in
'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/redcar-0.13.gemspec'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    cannot uninstall, check `gem list -d redcar`

so how can I uninstall redcar

PLEASE HELP

Thanks in Advance

Kausik

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in some versions of Rubygems that causes gemspec incompatibilities. Upgrading your Rubygems will remove this block:

```
gem update --system
```